# How to disable page create for custom post type, but allow a page with the post types slug to be created?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type called `integrations`, which I have registered like this:

```
register_post_type(
  'Integrations',
  theme_build_post_args(
    // $slug, $singular, $plural
    'integrations', 'Integration', 'Integrations',
    array(
      'menu_position' => 20,
      'has_archive'     => true,
      'public'          => false,
      'publicly_queryable'  => false,
      'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => false, 'with_front' => false ),
      'supports'            => array('title', 'revisions'),
      'taxonomies'      => array('categories'),
    )
  )
);
```

I don't want a page to be created upon registered the above post type, as I'm looking to create a `page` that sits on `/integrations` which will be much more customised. Also, I have subpages which sit under this page, so I'm looking for it to become a page so I can assign it as the `parent` to child pages. As such, I have added `'publicly_queryable'  => false` to the above.

Now, I have created a `page` called Integrations which sits on `/integrations`, but upon accessing it, it redirects to the homepage.

I'm certain this is because of `'publicly_queryable'  => false`, but, removing it would not solve my issue as the slug will exist as the post type is registered.

Is there a way around this?

### Edit:

1. Created `template_redirect` in `functions.php`:

```html
function custom_integrations_template() {
  if (is_page('integrations')) {
    get_template_part('page', 'integrations');
    exit();
  }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'custom_integrations_template');
```

2. Created `page-integrations.php` and added a template name:

```html
<?php

/*
* The template for displaying search results pages
*
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#search-result
* Template Name: Integrations
*/

get_header(); ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

3. Removed `'publicly_queryable'  => false` from my post type
4. Assigned the `Integrations` template to my Integrations page.
5. Added content to the Integrations page and updated
6. Flushed permalinks
7. Viewed `/integrations` and it doesn't show the content added in step 4?

It seems like it is still showing the page created when registering a post type, as my content on the page isn't showing?

Comment: You can use a template_redirect action for this, to detect if the page is `Integrations` and if it is you can include your custom template instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `'publicly_queryable' => false`. This tells wordpress to not let anyone access the page.

Try with a [template_include](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) action, and detect if the page slug is `integrations`:

```php
function custom_integrations_template($template) 
{
    if (is_page('integrations')) {
        $newTemplate = locate_template(['page-integrations.php']);

        if (! $newTemplate) {
           return new WP_Error('broken', 'Integrations template not found');
        }

        return $newTemplate;
    }

    return $template;
}

add_filter('template_include', 'custom_integrations_template', 99);
```

This will look for a `page-integrations.php` file in your theme directory when someone access `/integrations`.

You don't have to use `locate_template`, you can include the full path to your template: `__DIR__.'/path/to/your/template.php'`

Comment: Hi Zander, many thanks for your notes. I've edited my question to showcase my current status based on your answer.

Comment: @Freddy updated, try now, turns out `template_redirect` usage is not advised for this purpose

Comment: Thanks for the modification, however, still no luck. I've also tried `$newTemplate = __DIR__.'/page-integrations.php';`. In my `page-integrations.php` file, I've added raw HTML ("This is a test") to test if that prints - it doesn't. It looks like it isn't finding the `page-integrations.php` template at all? I've also tried increasing the priority from `99` to `999`

Comment: Something weird going on there, the above is from the documentation, I'm at a loss sorry

Comment: No worries. If it means anything, I've just inspected the body classes on the `/integrations` page, and it's returning the following: `archive post-type-archive post-type-archive-integrations`. Seems like it is still thinking its an archive template (no `archive-integrations.php` file exists).

Comment: Just a follow up, got it working. Had to set `has_archive` to `false` and then to clear WP caches, I had to `unregister_post_type()` and then `register_post_type()` again. Thanks for the assist!